# vbulletin custom field plugin

Tags: vbulletin

I have a question about the vbulletin 4 plugins . 
I need to create a plugin that add a new custom field to the registration form .
I don’t want to modify the "register" template or to add this custom field from the admin panel.
sorry i'm new to vbulletin developing and i need your help , or some references on how to work with plugins and custom fields.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Go to ACP - User Profile Fields - Add New User Profile Field and add a new field here. You do not need to modify anything.:)